# Magento export order in csv price symbol â‚¹

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

Magento export order in csv price symbol â‚¹ . How to change into rupees symbol

Comment: Check your CSV encoding. And please enhance your question a little, one-liners are not welcome here.

Comment: My question is that when export order in csv. Order total amount currency symbol coming like â‚¹ when open csv file in excel. I got the solution now. I added these char  chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) to csv file an d now rupees symbol is coming with total amount.

Comment: @Shekhar could you please explain what do you mean by "add these char chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) to csv file" is it like in my csv file i write rupeee symbol as " ₹chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)" ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127382)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) apped this to content of csv.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is issue of UTF-8 encoding Decode UTF-8 when you import and your problem were solved

`<?php echo utf8_decode(string);  ?>`

Comment: I used this one but know price symbol come like ? (question mark) this.  price symbol â‚¹  is comming on excel.

Comment: @ShekharSuman because Rupee symbol is not iso-8859 compliant.